# What is com.google.android.gm?

Tags: android, logcat, android-log

One of my logs is returning the following message:

`12-07 10:42:45.201 6622-17013/? D/DownloadManager: 23 Starting {Apk-apks_1.1.017-812_releaseVersion.apk} by {10112:com.google.android.gm}`

I believe `com.google.android.gm` represents my gmail account but not sure. Need more insights.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is the [gmail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes that is indeed the Gmail android app. Any links clicked via the Gmail app have this as the traffic source.

You can see the ID here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm